# Twilio Conversations - How to Create a new Conversation NOT in default service API

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-conversations

I can simply create a new Conversation using the default Conversation Service using
Twilio.Rest.Conversations.V1.Create()
but how do I create a new Conversation using a particular (non-default) Conversation Service using the API?
I can fetch the Conversation service I want: ServiceResource.Fetch(pathSid: "ISxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
but I can't see how to use that to create a new Conversation.

Is it not supported through programmatic API, and do I need to use the raw json to the URL instead?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I believe you are talking about using the Twilio API C# library. The [docs on creating a conversation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/conversation-resource#create-a-conversation-resource) seem to miss this, but you can create a conversation for a different service by providing it as the `pathChatServiceSid` option to the call to create.

```cs
using Twilio.Rest.Conversations.V1;

TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

var conversation = ConversationResource.Create(
  pathChatServiceSid: "ISXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
);
```

You can see more of this in the source code for the [ConversationResource](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/blob/61bee0bb7cc20f79070183ea4c4bce006eaccb2d/src/Twilio/Rest/Conversations/V1/Service/ConversationResource.cs) and [ConversationOptions](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/blob/61bee0bb7cc20f79070183ea4c4bce006eaccb2d/src/Twilio/Rest/Conversations/V1/Service/ConversationOptions.cs). I'm not a C# developer, so I hope I have interpreted that correctly for you.

Comment: Sweet, would be helpful and save time of other devs if mentioned in [Doc](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/user-resource#using-the-shortened-base-url)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks philnash, the github links you posted lead me in the right direction.

It turns out that the Twilio library seems to contain multiple namespaces with similar functionality

- Twilio.Rest.Conversations.V1.Conversation
- Twilio.Rest.Conversations.V1.Service.Conversation

Where the former one lacks the pathChatServiceSid parameter, but the latter (the one you pointed me to) does.

Thanks